# Can high network usage be detected and prevented in Tor?

Tags: onion-services, linux, censorship, deanonymization, debian

I was wondering if there is any way for Tor to detect high network usage in the context of transferring large files using a hidden service.

If so, what are the default prevention steps?

Comment: Well, dipend. Dipende by the settings of your torrc like: CellStatistics, DirReqStatistics, and so on.. if you have access to those log file you can get a lot of infos like number of client.... so if you can see that in the last 24 hours you get 1 client and 100GB of data transfer, you detected a high network usage in the context of transferring large files using a hidden service.